# Dapper does not warn or fail with missing data

Tags: c#-4.0, orm, dapper

Let's say I have a class (simplistic for example) and I want to ensure that the PersonId and Name fields are ALWAYS populated.

```
public class Person
{
    int PersonId { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Currently, my query would be:

```
Person p = conn.Query<Person>("SELECT * FROM People");
```

However, I may have changed my database schema from PersonId to PID and now the code is going to go through just fine.

What I'd like to do is one of the following:

1. Decorate the property PersonId with an attribute such as Required (that dapper can validate)
2. Tell dapper to figure out that the mappings are not getting filled out completely (i.e. throw an exception when not all the properties in the class are filled out by data from the query).

**Is this possible currently?** If not, can someone point me to how I could do this without affecting performance too badly?

**IMHO**, the second option would be the best because it won't break existing code for users and it doesn't require more attribute decoration on classes we may not have access to.

Comment: Not an answer, but I'd much rather use "select PersonID, Name, Address from People" instead of "select *". When the schema changes, your query will fail. Problem solved.

Comment: @Dag thanks for your comment but unfortunately that is not the case with Dapper. My Model might have mistypes such as FullName instead of Name in which case there is no exception at all. It just assumes that you did not want to map Name. Changes on either the schema OR model mismatches should throw an exception if I should so choose. See this gist (comments at the bottom of the page) for more info: https://gist.github.com/aboutdev/4945917

Answer (score 5):

At the moment, no this is not possible. And indeed, there are a lot of cases where it is actively useful to populate a partial model, so I wouldn't want to add anything *implicit*. In many cases, the domain model is an extended view on the data model, so I don't think option 2 can work - and I *know* it would break in a gazillion places in my code ;p If we restrict ourselves to the more explicit options...

So far, we have deliberately avoided things like attributes; the idea has been to keep it as lean and direct as possible. I'm not pathologically *opposed* to attributes - just: it can be problematic having to probe them. But maybe it is time... we could perhaps also allow simple column mapping at the same time, i.e.

```
[Map(Name = "Person Id", Required = true)]
int PersonId { get; set; }
```

where both `Name` and `Required` are optional. Thoughts? This is problematic in a few ways, though - in particular at the moment we only probe for *columns we can see*, in particular in the extensibility API.

The other possibility is an interface that we check for, allowing you to manually verify the data after loading; for example:

```
public class Person : IMapCallback {
    void IMapCallback.BeforePopulate() {}
    void IMapCallback.AfterPopulate() {
        if(PersonId == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("PersonId not populated");
    }
}
```

The interface option makes me happier in many ways:

- it avoids a lot of extra reflection probing (just one check to do)
- it is more flexible - you can choose what is important to you
- it doesn't impact the extensibility API

but: it is more manual.

I'm open to input, but I want to make sure we get it *right* rather than rush in all guns blazing.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question Mark. To answer your points, the attribute seems easier for a dev than implementing the interface. But the interface is cleaner and more consistent. However, the underlying issue still remains which is to optionally ensure when the data model is not being mapped. I may not want to do a callback for every record because it would be a lot of overhead. I just want to make sure that the columns I expect don't change. Here is something I did to test (warning: dragons ahead). I am in the process of creating a gist...

Comment: I created this gist: https://gist.github.com/aboutdev/4945917    Line 50 - 57 is the majority of the change. It's not in any way prod code but just a test to see if it is possible. What I'm verifying here is that the columns returned to me can be mapped by the data model. Thus if fat-fingered-freddy changes the data model field, the code will fail. Or if he changes the database field, the code will fail. I hope that clarifies what I'm trying to do? This way, we don't validate every row but only once (better?) so it should be a bit faster.

Comment: Another approach would be make a master switch to make things work like @AboutDev suggested (where all properties with a setter must be populated, if they aren't errors are thrown). The switch would probably be off by default. Devs that enable this switch and need objects with non-populated properties will have to create an extra layer of classes, a DB object layer, that caters entirely to the column names returned by the queries. This layer is different than the business layer where things can be null. Devs would then map the DB objects to Business objects.